# I want to output table based on what the user input

Tags: sql, database, oracle, toad

User required to input an APP_ID but optional to put MILESTONE_ID and TASK_ID. If MILESTONE_ID only the input, it should be the milestone only not include the task.

Ex. APP_ID: 1 MILESTONE_ID:341 TASK_ID: (blank) = output should be app_id and milestone only.

When APP_ID: 1 MILESTONE_ID: (blank) TASK_ID: 441 = output should be app_id and task only.

Lastly when user input a APP_ID: 1, MILESTONE_ID:341, TASK_ID: 441 = output should be app_id, task and milestone.

My current query is below:

```
SELECT APPLICATION, MILESTONE_NAME, TASK_NAME, FIELD_NAME, FIELD_ALIAS 
FROM TBL_APPLICATIONS A
    INNER JOIN TBL_WORKFLOWS B ON B.APPLICATION_FK = A.APPLICATION_PK
    INNER JOIN TBL_WORKFLOW_DEFINITION C ON C.WORKFLOW_FK = B.WORKFLOW_PK
    INNER JOIN TBL_MILESTONE D ON D.MILESTONE_PK = C.START_MILESTONE_FK  OR D.MILESTONE_PK =  C.END_MILESTONE_FK 
    INNER JOIN TBL_TASK_FOR_MILESTONE E  ON E.MILESTONE_FK =  D.MILESTONE_PK 
    INNER JOIN TBL_TASK F ON F.TASK_PK  =  E.TASK_FK strong text
    INNER JOIN TBL_REQ_FOR_TASK G ON  G.TASK_FK  = F.TASK_PK 
    INNER JOIN TBL_TASK_REQUIREMENTS H ON H.TASK_REQUIREMENT_PK = G.TASK_REQUIREMENT_FK 
WHERE  APPLICATION_PK = :APPLICATION_ID 
OR MILESTONE_PK = :MILESTONE_ID 
OR  TASK_PK = :TASK_ID
```

Output looks like this.

[image: I am stuck]

Comment: You can't change the `SELECT` list dynamically in SQL. If you're making the query from a programming language like PHP or Python, you can build it dynamically.

Comment: Is there supposed to be a difference between the two images?

Comment: @APC Oracle sir

Comment: @Barmar I'm thinking the same thing. But that's what my boss want. :(

Comment: @Barmar No. they're the same. Accidentally duplicate.

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to select a table from query like if i input from milestone_id, the task_id won't be affected. I mean milestone_id only shows.

Comment: AFAIK, There is no such way to create a dynamic oracle query only in oracle. You have to use Either PL/SQL or a front end language to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirements are slightly unclear. If you want to change the projection of the query or even remove the tables from the FROM clause, that cannot be done in pure SQL. Dynamically assembling queries requires PL/SQL or some other client language.

But if your requirement is simply to conditionally suppress the column value whether a parameter is populated, that can be done by testing each parameter, like this:

```
SELECT APPLICATION
      , case when :MILESTONE_ID is not null then MILESTONE_NAME end as MILESTONE_NAME
      , case when :TASK_ID is not null then TASK_NAME end as TASK_NAME
      , FIELD_NAME
      , FIELD_ALIAS 
FROM TBL_APPLICATIONS A
    INNER JOIN TBL_WORKFLOWS B ON B.APPLICATION_FK = A.APPLICATION_PK
    INNER JOIN TBL_WORKFLOW_DEFINITION C ON C.WORKFLOW_FK = B.WORKFLOW_PK
    INNER JOIN TBL_MILESTONE D ON D.MILESTONE_PK = C.START_MILESTONE_FK  OR D.MILESTONE_PK =  C.END_MILESTONE_FK 
    INNER JOIN TBL_TASK_FOR_MILESTONE E  ON E.MILESTONE_FK =  D.MILESTONE_PK 
    INNER JOIN TBL_TASK F ON F.TASK_PK  =  E.TASK_FK strong text
    INNER JOIN TBL_REQ_FOR_TASK G ON  G.TASK_FK  = F.TASK_PK 
    INNER JOIN TBL_TASK_REQUIREMENTS H ON H.TASK_REQUIREMENT_PK = G.TASK_REQUIREMENT_FK 
WHERE  APPLICATION_PK = :APPLICATION_ID 
and ( :MILESTONE_ID  is not null or :TASK_ID is not null )
and ( :MILESTONE_ID  is null or MILESTONE_PK = :MILESTONE_ID )
and ( :TASK_ID       is null or  TASK_PK = : )
```

Note that I have corrected the WHERE clause to include conditions that only filter on MILESTONE_ID or TASK_ID when they are populated.

Comment: this is the objective for clarity:

Ex. APP_ID: 1 MILESTONE_ID:341 TASK_ID: (blank) = output should be app_id and milestone only.

When APP_ID: 1 MILESTONE_ID: (blank) TASK_ID: 441 = output should be app_id and task only.

Comment: Lastly when user input a APP_ID: 1, MILESTONE_ID:341, TASK_ID: 441 = output should be app_id, task and milestone.

Comment: You can't change the structure of the projection in pure SQL but you can change whether column values are displayed. I have amended my answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thank you Sir! Appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: If you found this answer helpful please consider upvoting and/or accepting it. Accepted answers improve the value of this site for other Seekers.

Comment: ORA-01745: invalid host/bind variable name. But i figured out that it should be done in stored proc or function.